# What (if any) are the measurement units for neurotransmitters?

Tags: neurology, measurement, neurotransmitter

I've searched through the web for how to measure neurotransmitters (such as dopamine, serotonin, and oxytocin), but could not find any. Could someone please specify if there is a unit of measurement, like micrograms, for neurotransmitters? And if there is, can you please tell me which one? My hunch is some form of mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These substances are measured in mass concentration ([Example: Dopamine](https://www.drugs.com/dosage/dopamine.html)), that is, mass per volume. The standard SI unit for this is mg/ml, but I've also seen [ng/ml](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003562.htm) or other units.

This is because they are usually used in solutions as an infusion. If you were to be just talking about how much neurotransmitter you have, you'd use any unit of mass.

Comment: Did you mean mg/ml?

Comment: You said "ng/ml". It should be "m" instead of "n".

Comment: @RohanBhowmik I said the standard unit is mg/ml, but I've also seen nanogram (ng) per millilitre with a link to a source using nano litres.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right